# How can I keep the animated view on the screen while transitioning to another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uianimation

I have my main `ViewController` (`VC1`) that has a `[UIView animateWithDuration: animations:]` which brings up a new button. When said button is pressed I have my app go to another `ViewController` (`VC2`).

Everything works fine except that while the segue is happening ( `switching from VC1 to VC2` ) the screen that is sliding to the left (VC1) shows what was originally on `VC1` (before the `[UIView animateWithDuration: animations:]` took place ).

I have tried putting this into `viewWillDisappear`:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
  self.showProfile.center  = CGPointMake(50, 400, 150, 21);
}
```

Where showProfile is the `view/button` that was animated in from another location (`and the point 50, 400, 150, 21 is where it was animated to, and where I want it to stay relative to VC1 while it segues into VC2`)

It's a little problem and I was wondering if anybody had any quick solutions to this. Let me know if you dont understand and I'll try to explain it better

Comment: try using constraints instead of frames.

Comment: Placing "showProfile" on window instead of having it on VC view should help.